# Is one Level 2 data subscription sufficient?

Tags: market-data, tick-data

I am subscribed to Level 2 data from a single exchange. There are more exchanges offering Level 2 data subscription. However, with my single subscription I can see ask and bid sizes from all routing destinations, so I was wondering if there is any advantage in subscribing to Level 2 data feed from other exchanges as well? Are additional subscriptions redundant, or do they contain additional information?

EDIT:
Please note that I am not restricting the attention to any specific strategy and information required by it. My question is purely mathematical: Is the set of Level 2 information broadcast by a single exchange equivalent to the aggregate of Level 2 information from all exchanges, or is it strictly a subset missing potentially useful components?

Comment: Is this a *consolidated* feed of all exchanges? Also, whether you need a particular data set is entirely dependent on what you intend to do with it.

Comment: @chrisaycock I do not think the feed is consolidated, as it displays separate ask and bid information for destinations such as ARCA or ISLAND etc. Certainly, I'd like to know if there is potentially useful additional information in the other feeds that could potentially be utilized by a hypothetical strategy which is aware of it, as opposed to a feed from a single exchange only.